# Index: Wrong order and problems using \index in \section AND \subsection

Tags: macros, indexing, makeindex

I have two problems with the index in my .tex file.
[image]

1) How can I put the 1.10 behind the 1.3?
2) How can I stash the zero in from \section? (E.g. 1 instead of 1.0)

Unfortunately my MWE is not that 'minimal':

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 

\makeindex 
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand*{\indexpage}[2]{#1}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|indexpage{\thesubsection}}} 


\begin{document}
\section{English football league system}
\index{System}
%
\subsection{History}
Created in 1888.
%
\subsection{Structure}
\index{Structure}
At the top is the single division of the Premier League
%
\subsection{Cup eligibility}
\index{Cup}
Being members of a league at a particular level also affects eligibility for Cup.
%
\subsection{Sub 4}
%
\subsection{Sub 5}
%
\subsection{Sub 6}
%
\subsection{Sub 7}
%
\subsection{Sub 8}
%
\subsection{Sub 9}
%
\subsection{Carobao Cup}
\index{Cup}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately for references with this format, the sorting of `makeindex` is strictly "literal".  1.03 and 1.10 would sort in the desired (logical to humans but not to a computer) order.  but i'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add leading zeros so makeindex sorts, and then drop them while typesetting

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} 

\makeindex 
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\newcommand*{\indexpage}[5]{#2\ifnum#4=0 \else.#4\fi}
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|%
   indexpage
    {\ifnum\value{section}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{section}}%
    {\ifnum\value{subsection}<10 0\fi}{\arabic{subsection}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{English football league system}
\index{System}
%
\subsection{History}
Created in 1888.
%
\subsection{Structure}
\index{Structure}
At the top is the single division of the Premier League
%
\subsection{Cup eligibility}
\index{Cup}
Being members of a league at a particular level also affects eligibility for Cup.
%
\subsection{Sub 4}
%
\subsection{Sub 5}
%
\subsection{Sub 6}
%
\subsection{Sub 7}
%
\subsection{Sub 8}
%
\subsection{Sub 9}
%
\subsection{Carobao Cup}
\index{Cup}


\printindex
\end{document}
```